# don't work data.length when data returned from ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I trying to get some data in `json` type with ajax in jQuery, so I wrote this code :

```
$.ajax({
    url: link.attr('href'),
    type: 'post',
    data: 'post=true',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        if (data.length > 0) {
            ldLayer.fadeOut('slow');
        }else{
            alert('no data');
        }
    }
});
```

But when the `data` is `null` the `if` will true and `ldLayer.fadeOut('slow');` will run !

**UPDATE:**
The `console.log(data)` result is : `[null]`

Comment: If the data is `null`, it should fail on getting `data.length`. Are you sure data is `null`? Isn't it string `'null'`? In that case it passes correctly and it makes sense.

Comment: Based on your edit, `data` is an **array** with a single `null` member, so its `length` property is 1. `length` can only be 0 if the array is empty -- this array is not empty because it has a member. `[null]` is different from `[]`.

Comment: I updated my question, I wrote the `console.log` result. I trying the `data == 'null'` and `data == null` too before, but not work

Comment: try changinging the dataType on the request to text and console.logging out the data in the success callback... that should give you some clues on where things are falling down.

Comment: @apsillers Thanks, so how can I check in this mode ?

Comment: What version of jQuery? it sounds like you're using an older version of jQuery that allowed non-json results to be treated as json if it was empty string or null. Make sure your request returns an empty array, not null, when no results are returned.

Comment: @KevinB According to the edit, the OP is getting back `[null]` -- an array containing `null` -- which is a valid JSON response. Your advice is still sound, but it should read, "Make sure your request returns an empty array, not *an array containing `null`*..."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting back an array of results. In the problem case you describe, you're getting back an array with a single `null` element. An empty array (`[]`) has a length of 0, but an array with a single null element (`[null]`) has length 1.

In the client, you can check if any of the array's elements are non-`null`:

```
success: function(data){
    var foundSomething = false;

    for(var i=0; i<data.length; ++i) {
        if(data[i] !== null) foundSomething = true;
        break;
    }

    if(foundSomething) {
        ldLayer.fadeOut('slow');
    }else{
        alert('no data');
    }
}
```

**However**, a much better approach would be to fix your server-side code so it doesn't send back arrays with `null` elements. If you don't have control over the server code, however, the client-side solution I've provided above is your best bet.

Comment: Thanks, as you said I have a problem in my server side programming, so I changed that and my problem solved, but your code work for me before changing my server side code, so your code work for my question.

Answer (score 2):

Simply Check like this

```
if (data)   {
    ldLayer.fadeOut('slow');
} else {
    alert('no data');
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell whats coming in data ??

Comment: The `console.log(data)` result is : `[null]` and when I trying to `alert(data)` I will get an empty window

Comment: Multiple reasons may there for this problem.MIME type or returning null in response etc ..Please cross check once